# What is the best way to store long term and run a java script function in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a couple of utility java script function which I use for couple of websites. Currently I am opening  up the console and pasting the code there whenever I want to run it. Is there place in chrome, local disk or web where I can store this function and import / run it whenever I want, instead of copying and pasting it every time?

Comment: A userscript? An addon? Maybe just automate the tasks entirely, so it's not you who has to execute the code manually?

Comment: Sounds like a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) will do the job.